# Token Supply Question

Tags: solidity

The 10b tokens
transferred into the deployer address of that token from address 0x000000
are they real tokens?

https://etherscan.io/token/0x4574562E9310a94F9Ca962bd23168d8a06875b1A?a=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

thanks ,

Comment: They are [TROY](https://etherscan.io/token/0x4574562e9310a94f9ca962bd23168d8a06875b1a) tokens.

Comment: What is the 0x0000 address?

Comment: Usually  the zero address is used as sender when creating tokens or as recipient when burning them.

Answer (score 0):

> are they real tokens?

They are as "real" as any other tokens in the contract. Deep down, they are data representing accounting entries.

The deployment process usually mints tokens out of nowhere as I assume is the case here. The log entry of the "transfer" reflect that "from nowhere" aspect of the minting process.

The deployed has real tokens that didn't exist previously.

Hope it helps.